# Is there a website that reviews car hire/rental companies?

Tags: online-resources, car-rentals, automobiles

I am looking to rent a car in the States for a stint and I have no idea if one company is better than the other. In fact, some have horrible branding and although their prices are attractive, I don't know whether I would trust them.

The last thing I would want is to fly across the Atlantic to get bad experience with my rental. Is there any trust worthy website that reviews car rental companies?

Comment: Have you tried the usual suspects?  Google+, Yelp, Consumer Reports....

Comment: TripAdvisor lets you review almost anything travel-related. Have a look there.

Comment: Maybe you never noticed or just don't know, but when renting a car in major airports/rental hubs, all the rental companies use the same parking lots, contract the same maintenance companies. The main difference is the color of uniform their desk agents wear, their choice of car manufacturers and their pricing. If there is one domain where concurrency looks limited to me, that's car rental.

Comment: Actually I hunted through TripAdvisor and they do not host ratings or reviews of car rental companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trip Advisor is one of the best sources of genuine feedback/reviews.
On their website go to United States Forums
and type "car rentals" in the search bar.

You'll get your hands on more information than you need with people sharing their experiences with various car rentals.
A good idea will be to search reviews for a [particular car rental agency](http://www.tripadvisor.in/SearchForums?ff=3&geo=191&scope=2&q=hertz&x=-753&y=-376&returnTo=http%253A__2F____2F__www__2E__tripadvisor__2E__in__2F__ListForums__2D__g191__2D__i3__2D__United__5F__States__2E__html) to get better search results.